# UnregisterName if exist

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    <Button x:Name="myButton" Height="20" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Unregister The Name Name"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

vb.net

```
Class MainWindow

Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Dim myTextBlock As New TextBlock
    With myTextBlock
        .Height = 30
        .Width = 100
        .Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)
    End With
    Me.RegisterName(name:="myTextBlock", scopedElement:=myTextBlock)
    myGrid.Children.Add(myTextBlock)
End Sub

Private Sub myButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles myButton.Click
    If Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames.Contains("myTextBlock") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Done")
        Me.UnregisterName(name:="myTextBlock")
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

MessageBox doesnt open when I run this project and click **myButton**.

So, can you advice alternative code for following code?

> Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames.Contains("myTextBlock")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Dim myTextBlock As New TextBlock
    With myTextBlock
        .Height = 30
        .Width = 100
        .Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)
    End With
    Me.RegisterName(name:="myTextBlock", scopedElement:=myTextBlock)
    myGrid.RegisterName("myTextBlock", myTextBlock)
    myGrid.Children.Add(myTextBlock)
End Sub

Private Sub myButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles myButton.Click
    Dim btn As Object = Nothing
    btn = myGrid.Findname("myTextBlock")
    If (Not btn = Nothing) Then
         MessageBox.Show("Done")
         Me.UnregisterName(name:="myTextBlock")
         'myGrid.UnregisterName("myTextBlock")
    End If
End Sub
```